# How can I extract a row values corresponding to a particular column value ? ( variable number of columns in dataframe)

Tags: pandas

Say I have a data frame ( Stress Transfer) as below and every new data-frame as shown below will have variable number of columns like value 5 , 6 and so on...

| Type of load | value1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bending Moment | 50 | 2 | 21 | 22 |
| Radial | 70 | 2.2 | 19 | 23 |

So I need a output list like =[ value1, value2, Value 3, Value 4] corresponding to 'Bending Moment'

When I try this

```
Stress_Transfer_1= Stress_Transfer.loc[Stress_Transfer['Type of Load '] == 'BendingMoment']
```

I do not get any out put as I get an empty data frame. Please note I need something generic since the number of columns (Values) can vary with each new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If your typing is accurate, it looks you missed a space in your selection statement

```
Stress_Transfer_1= Stress_Transfer.loc[Stress_Transfer['Type of Load '] == 'BendingMoment']
```

should be

```
Stress_Transfer_1= Stress_Transfer.loc[Stress_Transfer['Type of Load '] == 'Bending Moment']
```